# how to get the 'id' for the update form to work?

Tags: php, html, mysql, session

My update form is not updating my database when I click the update button.

This is for a user management website that I'm making where the users need to update their profile after viewing it on another page.

When the user clicks on update link the following should happen:

1. The `id` variable is loaded in the url which redirects to the update page.
2. Then based on that, the webpage updates the user details in the database.

```
<?php

  require('config.php');
  }

  // Define variables and initialize with empty values
  $username = $email = $fullname = $phonenumber = $age = $city = $area 
    = $dateofbirth = $nationality = $about = $qualifications = 
    $interests = "";


  if(isset($_POST["id"]) && !empty($_POST["id"])){

    $id = $_POST["id"];
    $username = trim($_POST["username"]);
        if(empty($input_name)){
        $name_err = "Please enter a name.";
    } else{
        $name = $input_name;
    }


        $email = trim($_POST["email"]);
        if(empty($input_email)){
        $email_err = "Please enter a email.";
       } else{
        $email = $input_email;
        }



        $fullname = trim($_POST["fullname"]);
        if(empty($input_fullname)){
        $fullname_err = "Please enter your fullname.";
    } else{
        $fullname = $input_fullname;
    }



        $phonenumber = trim($_POST["phonenumber"]);
        if(empty($input_phonenumber)){
        $phonenumber_err = "Please enter you mobile or landline number.";
    } else{
        $phonenumber = $input_phonenumber;
    }


        $age = trim($_POST["age"]);
        if(empty($input_age)){
        $age_err = "Please enter your age.";
    } else{
        $age = $input_age;
    }



        $city = trim($_POST["city"]);
        if(empty($input_city)){
        $city_err = "Please enter the name of emirate.";
    } else{
        $city = $input_city;
    }


        $area = trim($_POST["area"]);
       if(empty($input_area)){
         $area_err = "Please enter the area where your live.";
       } else{
        $area = $input_area;
       }


        $dateofbirth = trim($_POST["dateofbirth"]);
        if(empty($input_dateofbirth)){
            $dateof_err = "Please enter your dateof birth.";
        } else{
            $dateofbirth = $input_dateofbirth;
        }


        $nationality = trim($_POST["nationality"]);
        if(empty($input_nationality)){
            $nationality_err = "Please enter your nationality.";
        } else{
            $nationality = $input_nationality;
        }


        $about = trim($_POST["about"]);
            if(empty($input_about)){
            $about_err = "Please write a little about yourself.";
        } else{
            $about = $input_about;
        }


        $qualifications = trim($_POST["qualifications"]);
            if(empty($input_qualifications)){
            $qualifications_err = "Please enter your qualifications.";
        } else{
            $qualifications = $input_qualifications;
        }


        $interests = trim($_POST["interests"]);
        if(empty($input_interests)){
            $interests_err = "Please some of your interests.";
        } else{
            $interests = $input_interests;
        }


    if(empty($username_err) && empty($email_err) && empty($fullname_err) && 
         empty($phonenumber_err) && empty($age_err) && empty($city_err) && 
        empty($area_err) && empty($dateofbirth_err) && empty($nationality_err) 
            && empty($about_err) && empty($qualifications_err) && 
           empty($interests_err) ){

  }

  $dateofbirth = trim($_POST["dateofbirth"]);
  $nationality = trim($_POST["nationality"]);
  $about = trim($_POST["about"]);
  $qualifications = trim($_POST["qualifications"]);
  $interests = trim($_POST["interests"]);

  $sql = "UPDATE accounts SET username = :username, email = :email , 
     fullname = :fullname , phonenumber = :phonenumber , age = :age , city = 
     :city , area = :area, dateofbirth = :dateofbirth , nationality = 
     :nationality , about = :about , qualifications = :qualifications , 
     interests = :interests WHERE id = :id ";

  // In this case we can use the account ID to get the account info.
  if($stmt = $con->prepare($sql)){
    // Bind variables to the prepared statement as parameters
    $stmt->bindParam(":username", $param_username, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindParam(":email", $param_email, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindParam(":fullname", $param_fullname, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $stmt->bindParam(":phonenumber", $param_phonenumber, 
    PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $stmt->bindParam(":age", $param_age, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindParam(":city", $param_city, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindParam(":area", $param_area, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindParam(":dateofbirth", $param_dateofbirth, 
    PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindParam(":nationality", $param_nationality, 
    PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindParam(":about", $param_about, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindParam(":qualifications", $param_qualifications, 
     PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindParam(":interests", $param_interests, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindParam(":id", $param_id, PDO::PARAM_INT);

    // Set parameters
    $param_username = $username;
    $param_fullname = $fullname;
    $param_phonenumber = $phonenumber;
    $param_age = $age;
    $param_city = $city;
    $param_area = $area;
    $param_dateofbirth = $dateofbirth;
    $param_nationality = $nationality;
    $param_about = $about;
    $param_qualifications = $qualifications;
    $param_interests = $interests;

    $param_id = $_SESSION["id"];

    // Attempt to execute the prepared statement
    if($stmt->execute()){
      // Password updated successfully. Destroy the session, and 
      redirect to login page
        session_destroy();
        header("location: profilepage.php");
      exit();
    } else{
      echo "Oops! Something went wrong. Please try again later.";
    }
    }
    // Close statement
    unset($stmt);
    }

    // Close connection
    unset($con);
    }else{
      // Check existence of id parameter before processing further
      if(isset($_GET["id"]) && !empty(trim($_GET["id"]))){
      // Get URL parameter
      $id =  trim($_GET["id"]);

      // Prepare a select statement
      $sql = "SELECT * FROM accounts WHERE id = :id";
      if($stmt = $con->prepare($sql)){
        // Bind variables to the prepared statement as parameters
        $stmt->bindParam(":id", $param_id);

        // Set parameters
        $param_id = $id;

        // Attempt to execute the prepared statement
        if($stmt->execute()){
          if($stmt->rowCount() == 1){
            /* Fetch result row as an associative array. Since the 
               result set contains only one row, we don't need to use while loop 
            */
            $row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

            // Retrieve individual field value
            $username = $row["username"];
            $fullname = $row["fullname"];
            $phonenumber = $row["phonenumber"];
            $age = $row["age"];
            $city = $row["city"];
            $area = $row["area"];
            $dateofbirth = $row["dateofbirth"];
            $nationality = $row["nationality"];
            $about = $row["about"];
            $qualifications = $row["qualifications"];
            $interests = $row["interests"];
          } else{
            // URL doesn't contain valid id. Redirect to error page
            header("location: error.php");
            exit();
          }

          } else{
            echo "Oops! Something went wrong. Please try again later.";
          }
        }

        // Close statement
        unset($stmt);

        // Close connection
        unset($con);
      }  else {
        // URL doesn't contain id parameter. Redirect to error page
        header("location: error.php");
        exit();
      }
    }
?>
```

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>USER DETAILS</title>

  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Skranji" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Rubik" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Hanalei+Fill" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Indie+Flower" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="Non-profit opportunities2.css?v=<?php 
      echo time(); ?>">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>
<body>

  <div class="grid-container">
  <!--Contains the Main heading-->
    <div class = "heading">
      <h1>BeHelp</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="grid-1">
      <!--Sub-Heading-->
      <div class="head">
        <h3>''''</h3>
      </div>

      <H5>Update Details</H5>
      <br><br>

      <form action="<?php echo 
        htmlspecialchars(basename($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])); ?>" method="post"> 

        <div class="form-group">Username: <input type="text" name="username" value="<?php echo $username ; ?>" ></div><br><br>

        <div class="form-group">Email:<input type="email" name="email" value="<?php echo $email ; ?>" ></div><br><br>

        <div class="form-group">Fullname:<input type="text" name="fullname" value="<?php echo $fullname ; ?>" ></div><br><br>

        <div class="form-group">Age:<input type="number" name="age" value="<?php echo $age ;?>" ></div><br><br>

        <div class="form-group">Phone Number:<input type="number" name="phonenumber" value="<?php echo $phonenumber ; ?>" ></div><br><br>

        <div class="form-group">City:<input type="text" name="city" value="<?php echo $city ; ?>" ></div><br><br>

        <div class="form-group">Area:<input type="text" name="area" value="<?php echo $area ; ?>" ></div><br><br>

        <div class="form-group">Date of birth:<input type="date" name="dateofbirth" value="<?php echo $dateofbirth ; ?>" required></div><br><br>

        <div class="form-group">Nationality:<input type="text" name="nationality" value="<?php echo $nationality ;?>" required></div><br><br>

        <div class="form-group">About:<input type="text" name="about" value="<?php echo $about ; ?>" required></div><br><br>

        <div class="form-group">Qualifications:<input type="text" name="qualifications" value="<?php echo $qualifications ;?>" required></div><br><br>

        <div class="form-group">Interests:<input type="text" name="interests" value=" <?php echo $interests ;?>" required></div><br><br>

        <div class="form-group"><input type="submit" name="update" value="Update Data"></div><input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $_GET['id']; ?>"/>

      </form>

    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

However, the details have still not been updated after so many tries . 
After clicking the update button the page loads but no details are being updated when I check the profile page .

I have edited the code above while I was trying to figure out the answer but the database is still not getting updated .

The code is not reading the ID parameter in the URL which is why it is being unable to make any changes to the database .

I added the exception and i still didn't get any syntax errors . I have been trying to figure this out for whole one day now . I have added HTML code in case of any reference is needed . But the main fault lies in PHP CODE . I want someone to tell me how should the code successfully read the ID of each user so the database can be updated .

Comment: No errors? Do you have exceptions on?

Comment: No I haven't put any exceptions in it . But i have checked it in a couple php code testers online and all show no syntax error .

Comment: Do that, it will tell you errors.

Comment: I did. it still doesn't show any errors

Comment: can you show complete url ?

Comment: try to echo this line `$id = $_POST["id"];` and add `die();` after this